# Read only swagger enum elements

Tags: swagger, openapi

Is there way to define enum list entry as read only? Now I have

```
type: object
description: |
  VISA card
properties:
  id:
    type: integer
    description: Internal ID of the card.
    example: 1
    minimum: 1
    readOnly: true
status:
  type: string
  required: true
  description: Current status of the card.
  enum:
    - STATUS_ENABLED
    - STATUS_DISABLED
    - STATUS_DELETED # <-- I Want this to be read only!
```

Now in patch operation I don't want to redefine above, but instead use it like:

```
requestBody:
  description: VISA card data to be updated.
  required: true
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        $ref: ../../index.yaml#/components/schemas/VisaCard
```

However, the API behind doesn't allow the status to be set to `STATUS_DELETED`. How to do this?

EDIT:

To clarify, PATCH should only be able to use `STATUS_ENABLED` and `STATUS_DISABLED`.

Comment: Do you mean that PATCH should not include the `status` property? Or do you mean that PATCH can only use `status` = `STATUS_ENABLED` and `STATUS_DISABLED` but not `STATUS_DELETED`?

Comment: Latter one. PATCH can only use STATUS_ENABLED and STATUS_DISABLED.

Comment: Did you try to use `allOf` / `anyOf` to build the status object?

Comment: @csaar yes, didn't work. Well, actually it did with ReDoc, but didn't with swagger editor.